# Laravel 5 Elixir - Not creating more than one output file after multiple mix calls

Tags: css, sass, gulp, laravel-elixir

I have my Gulp file set up:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
  mix.sass('app.scss').sass('admin.scss');
});
```

Which in my eyes should take both scss files and compile them into the public css folder.

However, it just creates one app.css file and doesn't create the admin.css file.

My terminal shows:

```
[23:01:43] Running Sass: resources/assets/sass/app.scss
[23:01:44] Running Sass: resources/assets/sass/admin.scss
[23:01:44] Finished 'watch' after 315 ms
[23:01:44] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Sass Compiled!
[23:01:45] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Sass Compiled!
```

So whats happening with the admin.scss file?

Comment: Oh no... I have the _exact_ same problem and still no correct answer. I've tried everything :(

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to specify the output folder for each file (and also restart gulp / gulp watch)

```
elixir(function(mix) {
  mix
    .sass('app.scss', './public/css/app.css')
    .sass('admin.scss', './public/css/admin.css');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once again, people at Larachat have pointed me in the right direction, so I thought I put this info here.

Turns out it's pretty easy, and it's documented: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/elixir#sass

Just put the files in an array instead of calling sass two times, like this:

```
mix.sass(['app.scss', 'admin.scss'], 'public/css')
```

Comment: It seems laravel took this feature away in laravel 5.5. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#sass.